# Ruby PG Connection ConversionError

Tags: ruby, postgresql

when I try to establish a connection to my Postgres database via the pg-ruby gem I get the following error (while initializing the connection):

```
class Source
    attr_accessor :conn 

    def initialize(username = 'postgres', password = 'postgres', db_name:)
        conn = PG::Connection.open(user: username, password: password, dbname: db_name)
    end
end
```

The database I try to connect with is empty, but I get the following error and can't really figure out why:

```
home/mkrs/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:599:in `write': "\\xC2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

If I run `Encoding.default_external` I get:

```
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: In `initialize` you probably mean `@conn = ....` as otherwise you just make a local variable and trash it.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?')
```

maybe some strange characters may be lost, but no errors will be raised.